# create a dropdown of unique options

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

There are 2 SQLite tables in my db, units.id,UnitName and departments.Unit,Department...
units.id and departments.Unit are the same.

The following will list the UnitName for each department, in my example that is 10 of the same UnitName. I am looking for a slick way to list only the unique UnitNames. Pardon my ignorance because I know this is easy..

```
<?php 
foreach ($departments as $dept)
{
   foreach ($units as $unit)
   {
      if ($dept['Unit'] == $unit['id'])
      {
          $options[$dept['id']] = $unit['UnitName'];;
      }
   }
}
echo form_dropdown('unit',$options,'0');
?>
```

Comment: in sql yeah there are easy way to do it but in php not that i know. Do you need a function or a way how to do it

Comment: See [array_unique](http://us.php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php). Also, if you're saving the array by id, the id won't repeat every time that you get the same id, it will overwrite the previous occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Some lovely detail;

```
$seenBeforeArray[];
$size = sizeof($dept);
for ($i=0; $i < $size ; $i++) {
    if (in_array($dept[$i]['UnitName'],$seenBeforeArray[])){
        unset($dept[$i]);
    } else {
        array_push($seenBeforeArray, $dept[$i]['UnitName']);
    }
}
```